# Sorting a List View causes the fields to look blank

Tags: list-view, sorting

I have a weird issue that I'm having trouble tracking down. When clicking a column header on some list views to sort, the fields are all present but all of the information looks either blank or the font might have changed to white... if you highlight the entire page or refresh it, the view is fine and it won't happen again until you close your browser and return.

We're on SharePoint 2013 and the clients range from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1, IE 10 & 11 mostly. The users have reported this back as far as a couple months.

Thanks,
jb

Answer (score 0):

We had the same symptoms.  We are using SharePoint 2013 and IE11.  For us, IE11 had Enterprise Mode enabled.  Once we turned off Enterprise Mode, the issue no longer happened.